# How do I communicate that something is a tutorial button

Tags: touch, interface

I made an (ios) arcade game that is rather unconventional, and as a result many people wont exactly know what to do or what the controls are when they first open it. As a results I have had to add a rectangular "Tutorial" button on my main menu screen so that when I hand it to people, or other people hand it to people (etc) its all ok.  FYI: When the game first opens it does go to a tutorial, I just wanted it to be accessible for repeats if necessary

In the original build I designed all the buttons and had labels on them, however the artist inside of me says that doesn't look good, so I had a friend redesign them.

The new buttons are bi-colored and very minimalist (usually with the outline of a shape in them).  We came up with simbols that work for "return", "play", and "leaderboard" that work... however we can not come up with one for "tutorial".

What would be a clear symbol that could be put on a "tutorial" button?

Here is a picture of the screen. That grey shape is meerly a placeholder.  The button on the top right opens a "Credits" page.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a level select? When you do you could disguise the tutorial as the first level.

Comment: Why do you spell out STORE then?  Why not just have a shopping cart?

Comment: I needed to be able to acids the tutorial whenever even after the first play so I made the button.

Comment: And then for the store button, I don't really know I just think the stuff fits together nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The most common glyph/icon I've seen for a tutorial is a Question Mark (?), although of course this can also mean a more general 'help' area. Other icons I have seen are a book or a blackboard.

To give anything more specific than that, I'd have to know more about what sort of game it is, what other icons you're using.

Comment: I've also seen a mortarboard being used.

Comment: Added a picture.  Those are both good ideas that I will have to play with!

Answer (score 1):

There is a common image used for a tutorial. Use it.

[image]

(But not this one...this one I grabbed off of google at http://wiki.minetest.net/images/thumb/3/3b/Tutorial_logo.png/150px-Tutorial_logo.png)